# Optimal use of StreamBuilder?

Tags: flutter, flutter-futurebuilder, flutter-streambuilder

The [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) doc says

> The future must have been obtained earlier, e.g. during State.initState, State.didUpdateWidget, or State.didChangeDependencies. It must not be created during the State.build or StatelessWidget.build method call when constructing the FutureBuilder. If the future is created at the same time as the FutureBuilder, then every time the FutureBuilder's parent is rebuilt, the asynchronous task will be restarted.

I'm guessing the same is true for [StreamBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html) but that doc doesn't give similar guidance. Is StreamBuilder fundamentally different from FutureBuilder in this regard?

Thanks!

Comment: See [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77760360/12349734) It explains how/why.

Comment: Heh, that link links to my video, which I can also link here: https://youtu.be/sqE-J8YJnpg

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should also initiate the `StreamBuilder` within the `initState`, as discussed in my previous [Q/A about `FutureBuilder`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77760360/12349734).

This approach prevents unnecessary repainting of your UI and `StreamBuilder` with each rebuild (for example, when triggered by `setState`).

---

The reason (I think) why it's only updated in the documentation for `FutureBuilder` is since they needed to edit the documentation [after a proposed issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/112676) explaining why you *should* use `initState`.

Comment: Thanks. Followup question — Presently, for a stateless widget that contains a StreamBuilder I instantiate the stream in the constructor. Is there a performance benefit to refactoring into a StateFull widget, simply so that the stream can be instantiated in initState?

Comment: @barcolounger Yes, it's better to use `initState` cause otherwise, your widget will still be rebuilt. See also - https://stackoverflow.com/a/71212481/12349734